# VPN software to connect to a Remote Access Server

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, vpn, remote-access

I have a Galaxy S2 from Virgin Mobile. My home network is Windows Server 2012. I'm using RAS to connect to my home network from other locations on a Windows 8 laptop. I have several SharePoint sites within my home network that I'd like to test from my phone. Most of the software I find on Google Play when searching VPN is to mask my browsing history or act as a proxy server. I'd like to VPN into my network from my phone.

I also have a Netgear Nighthawk R7000 wi-fi router, but I'd rather only use that if it's my only option. Doing some searches seems to say that Android is not supported for that router anyway.

What free or paid software can I use that doesn't require my phone being rooted?

If my only option is to root, what's the best ROM for my phone?

Then..

What free or paid software is best for a rooted phone?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, the first and third part of your question (asking for an app) is expressivley off-topic here (but you might wish to check [this list](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=115)). For the middle part, please see [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575). (one more hint: Don't ask multiple questions in one post; Q&A sites like this work best with one question per post ;) Good luck!

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip and the links.  The native VPN client on the phone worked fine.  I forgot that it existed.  Never needed it until now.

Comment: Thanks for the update, spex5. Would you mind making that an answer, including a few basic steps on how you enabled it? That would be pretty helpful to other users. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that using the native VPN client on Android is sufficient for this (I have 4.1.2).  From the home screen, hit menu, settings, more settings, VPN, Add VPN network, put in the host name / ip address of your RAS.  Default is PPTP, which worked for me, you will be prompted to enter your domain credentials.

Currently, I am going to try to the Paranoid Anroid ROM for my phone.  http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/orig-development/rom-paranoidandroid-4-2-beta3-t2603784  Running stock now.  Phone is getting old.  Hopefully this will extend it's usable life.